# Are these statement true? or false? Prove it.

Tags: general-topology

Hey I would be very grateful if you can tell which of these 4 statement are true and which of them are not (working in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb R^2$):

1- A set $K = \{p_1, p_2, ..., p_k\}$ and a point $q \notin K$, can be separated by two
disjoint open sets.

2- A set $K = \{p_1, p_2,· · ·\}$ and a point $q \notin K$, can be separated by two
disjoint open sets.

3- Two disjoint non-empty compact sets $K$ and $L$ can be separated by two
disjoint open sets.

4- A compact set $K$ and a closed set $F$, which are disjoint, can be separated
by two disjoint open sets.

PS: I should prove the statement when its true and give a counter example for the statement when its false. They were 6 statements, I solved 2 of them and I am now stuck with these 4. Can anybody help me please? Hint, sketch or something, I really don't need much. Thank you :)

Comment: What (kind of) topological space are you working in? That is highly relevant information.

Comment: it is not mentioned in the question, maybe its the discrete space?

Comment: In the discrete space, every subset is an open set. But it is also closed in a sense..

Comment: No its in R space or R^2! sorry

Comment: in the first proposition K is finite and in the second K is infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a sketch of a proof for the $4$th one. (Be sure you can justify each step!) Two of the other three will then follow directly, since they're just special cases of the $4$th. The other is false (see if you can figure out which one, and come up with an idea for a counterexample).

**Proof Sketch**: I denote an open ball of radius $r>0$ about a point $x$ by $B(x;r).$ Assume that $K$ and $F$ are non-empty, since otherwise it's trivial.

Let $W$ be the complement of $F,$ so that $W$ is open and is a superset of $K$. Then for each point $x\in K,$ there is some greatest $r>0$ such that $B(x;r)$ is contained entirely in $W$. Call this greatest $r$ by $r_x$ for each $x\in K$.

Cover $K$ by $$\left\{B\left(x;\frac{r_x}2\right):x\in K\right\}.$$ Reduce to a finite subcover $\mathcal C$. Then $U=\bigcup\mathcal C$ is an open superset of $K$, and the closure of $U$ is the union of the closures of the elements of $\mathcal C$ (since the closure of a finite union is the union of the closures). It can then be shown that the closure of $U$ is again a subset of $W$. Let $V$ be the complement of the closure of $U$. Then $U,V$ are disjoint, open, with $K\subseteq U$ and $F\subseteq V$.

Comment: I think the second statement is false, right?

Comment: Am sorry but no I can't disprove it but it seem logic to me since K contains infinite points.

Comment: As a hint, think about sequences.

Comment: we didn't study them yet

Comment: Hmm...well, that makes it harder. Do you know any countably-infinite sets that are not closed?

Comment: the N set is infinite and countable

Comment: True, but it is also closed.

Comment: Does the term "dense set" mean anything to you?

Comment: I can't think of one sorry, what about you?

Comment: You've never talked about dense sets?

Comment: No we've never talked about them

Comment: Without sequences or dense sets, this gets tricky! I can't think of any more hints, sadly. Consider the set $$K=\left\{\frac1n:n\text{ a positive integer}\right\}$$ and the point $q=0$ for a counterexample.

Comment: wow that is great! Thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome. Be sure that you understand how to justify all the steps in my proof sketch.